# When I write posts I usually have to use non breaking space element in order to keep margins in between the sentences. why?

Tags: tinymce

When I write posts I usually have to use non breaking space element in order to keep margins in between the sentences. In other words  - the text looks good in my editor, it is with spaces, but when I save it and preview it - it is all together, without spaces. Why it is like this?

Comment: Are you talking about all together on the vertical?

Comment: yes. all the text in the posts editor goes as I want, but than published it is altogether without spaces. So, I have to put the nbsp element in the break area. It is ok with me, but for my clients it is really anoying.

Comment: Did you mean paragraphs, or really the sentences. If you meant paragraphs, did you remove the 'wpautop' filter? Also, tinymce has an option in the settings to stop remove 'p' and 'br' tags I believe.

Comment: This question is both **too localized** and is off-topic. It is probably better suited for the [wordpress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support).

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is CSS related...have you used firebug or anything like that to inspect your HTML/CSS?

Comment: It is not about wordpress.org. I use the latest wordpress version. Shane> how to remove this filter? 'wpautop'

Comment: I think you are right. It is a HTML/CSS issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add this to your theme's style.css and add margin beneath the paragraphs on the live site:

```
p { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
```

Hope that helps. Good luck!